# Does CMake handle include path stuff as well?

Tags: c++, cmake, header, linker

To add **VulkanSDK** to my project in CMake I used `find_package()` and `target_link_libraries()` and then edit my VSCode project configuration by adding to the include path.

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "D:/Programs/VulkanSDK/1.1.85.0/Include"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.17763.0",
            "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Was I supposed to use cmake to include these headers and not use the VSCode project configuration ?

Comment: [include_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include_directories.html)?

Comment: Apparently yes `target_include_directories`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [set the `compileCommands` variable](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/master/Documentation/LanguageServer/c_cpp_properties.json.md) in the configuration you posted and [tell CMake to generate the compile commands](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS.html).

```
cmake -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:Bool=true ...
```

This way CMake creates a JSON database of all the command lines it used to compile your code and VSCode can use the same commands to provide intellisense.

> Note that this method only works with the Makefile generators listed on the CMake page and the Ninja generator.

Comment: Is the method you posted the recommended way of doing includes ? Like is it better than my setup ? My gripe is that I might be doing it wrong.

Comment: For CMake, `target_link_libraries` should be enough for *the build* to handle includes, no need to `target_include_directories`. CMake does not need or use the VSCode project configuration. That is only used by VSCode to provide intellisense. My method is better when it works because intellisense is provided using the exact same commands that are used to compile. When it doesn't work, you can try to reproduce them manually with `"defines" : [...], "includePath": [...]` to get intellisense to work (tell you the correct type for each variable etc.).

Comment: So the main question is, does the build work? If yes, don't modify the CMake configuration. Does intellisense work correctly? Then either just fix the VSCode configuration or modify both to use the compile commands database.